# Run Maven plugin globally

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I'm trying to get a maven plugin (specifically Jacoco) to run on every maven project, but I can't find much info on this. I don't think settings.xml would work and the lifecycle extension documentation isn't very helpful either.
Any ideas?

Comment: "every maven project" are these sub module of a multi-module project?

Comment: No, I mean literally any project I could potentially run on a machine.

Comment: You have to configure jacoco in every project because its configuration will be different depending upon whether or not it is a multi-module project or a single module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you declare such plugins in a company parent POM and use it as parent in all your projects.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks

Comment: Why afraid? What is the problem with that?

Comment: Because now I need to edit a couple hundred pom files.

Comment: If you don't have a company POM already, it would probably be wise to start one.

Answer (score 0):

according to maven doc

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

I think that you can't enforce a plugin on every maven project of a given host. there's no settings directive to do that.

Anyway you can facilitate the command line plugin dedicated goal through `pluginGroups` settings section.